# Merging Historical prices in R; having trouble with ordering by dates

Tags: r

like I said in the title, I am having trouble ordering the prices of historical data by dates. I have the data frame:

```
head(goog.merge)
        Date goog.price nasdaq.price
1 0001-10-20   306.7987     21.74104
2 0001-10-20   311.2593     23.32575
3 0001-10-20   370.3703     24.95281
4 0001-10-20   564.5264     37.99543
5 0001-11-20   300.2553     18.79405
6 0001-11-20   307.6978     22.02833
```

but when I use the order function:

```
goog.merge <- goog.merge[order(goog$Date, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

the data just gets jumbled in a seemingly unordered way:

```
Date goog.price nasdaq.price
100  0001-03-20   361.4742     24.71855
352        <NA>   750.2600     57.56088
604        <NA>   308.8866     24.67877
1105       <NA>   577.2426     36.66454
1358       <NA>   334.2763     21.22208
101  0001-03-20   551.9490     37.86218
```

This is what I used to input data:`enter code here`

```
 goog <- read.table("/Users/bhumphreys/Downloads/Google_closing.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")[c("Date","Adj.Close")]
```

And then I merged goog and nasdaq(inputed using same method), converted to date:

```
goog.merge <- merge(goog, nasdaq, by = "Date")
goog.merge[,c("Date")] <- as.Date(goog.merge[,c("Date")])
```

am I doing something wrong in ordering my data?

Comment: Hi Brian, is your Date column in date format? you can check by doing `class(goog.merge$Date)` that might be the problem, it might be class factor or character. If that is the case, you could transform it using the *lubridate* package

Comment: Did you convert `goog.merge$Date` to date format after reading in the file? The `Date` values (e.g., `0001-10-20`) look like what you get if you don't specify the correct format when running the `as.Date` function. For example, `as.Date("01-10-2015")` gives `0001-10-20`. But `as.Date("01-10-2015", format="%m-%d-%Y")` give the correct date `2015-01-10`.

Comment: @ Derek @eipi10 The Date column is in date format. I have included more of my previous code

Comment: Based on what you've posted so far, it seems probable that your dates got converted incorrectly due to lack of an appropriate format argument (see my previous comment). For example, do you really have NASDAQ stock prices from October 20, 0001? Or are these actually prices from the ROMEX or GAULEX?

Comment: I figured it out. R's date format is ordered as year/month/day and input from historical data is order month/day/year. However I now need to switch the ordering of the date components; is there a function for this? I have not found one

Comment: Just saw your post. you are correct about the format

Comment: The `format` argument to `as.Date` tells R the format of your dates so that R knows how to parse them properly. Based on what you've provided so far, the example in my first comment is probably what you need. Let me know if that doesn't work. For more info on date format arguments in R, see the help for `strptime`.

Comment: Very helpful thank you